# How to get the size of an iOS app without being enrolled in the developer program?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I want to analyze the size of an iOS app I created using flutter. As per [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size) flutter doc, you have to archive your app in Xcode and distribute it (Ad Hoc, Development, or Enterprise) after to see the size of your app. However, I am, unfortunately, not enrolled in the apple developer program since I'm only doing some testing for my bachelor's thesis and thus can't distribute it.
So how do I get the size of my flutter iOS release build?

One thing I did try, was just checking the app size in the iOS settings (General>Storage), but I'm not sure that's really accurate because the flutter release build is surprisingly a lot bigger in size compared to the debug build (110 MB vs 230 MB) according to the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select "Generic iOS device" from the list of devices.
2. Build your project.
3. Search for .app file and copy that file to some other location.
4. Zip that file.
5. Change extension from .zip to .ipa. It will reconfirm if you want to keep the same or update it to the new one.

This will give you **APPROX** size of your app.

Comment: it will be the size of simulator build. The size will be different than actual ipa.

Comment: Inteast of simulator we can select "Generic iOS Device" option

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The zipping in step 4 will give me the approx. download size of the app, right? So if I want the actual size of the app on the device (not the compressed download size), just skip steps 4 and 5, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please check section `Create the App Size Report` in below link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what Apple won't let me do without being an enrolled developer